# React Firestore Connection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to connect a database to my react application. I have managed to successfully connect it and the user register, but in the Login.js file, I'm not able to check a specific parameter.

In my case the `doc.data()` is always there, and I can only check if the user has been found. I can successfully run through the database and see that the user is there, but I cannot use the else (in case a user is not found).

Here is the function that does that:

```
const logCustomer = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const q = query(collection(db, "customers"), where("username", "==", username), where("password", "==", password));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    // the document exists and has data, so check if the username and password match
    const data = doc.data();
    if (data.username === username && data.password === password) {
      console.log('User found!');
    }
  })
}
```

I tried creating an error handling behaviour, but doc.data() is always there.

Comment: If there are matching documents then `data()` will never return `undefined` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query). Can I ask why are you not using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth) for authenticating users?

Comment: You are very right, this project has started with the sole purpose of authenticating customers, but then turned into something else. I need to take it one step back. Thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the case where a user with the given username/password is not found, you can just check whether you got any or no results from the database:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "customers"), where("username", "==", username), where("password", "==", password));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
if (querySnapshot.empty) {
  console.log("User not found");
}
else {
  console.log("User found");
}
```

As Dharmaraj commented though, it's probably better to leave authentication to a dedicated service such as Firebase Authentication.